# Having hard time understanding how to us void printSp(int) in this given task,

Tags: c

*I only really understand how to do equation in program I need help on how to approach this task, also I not really sure whats its asking of me to do.*

Suppose you are given a function with the following declaration:

```
void printSp(int); /* prints specified number of spaces */
```

Write a function named `printTri` that takes a single argument, a character, and returns an integer value. If the character is not a capital letter (between 'A' and 'Z'), then the function simply returns 0. Otherwise, if it is a capital letter, the function will print a triangle of characters that looks like this:    A   ABA  ABCBA ABCDCBA

NOTE: WIth a fixed-width font, the center letter in each row would line up. Write this out for yourself on paper, to figure out how many spaces should be printed on each line before the characters start. The bottom line has zero spaces. How many spaces should the top line have? The letter passed in becomes the highest letter in the triangle. For example, to print the triangle above, the caller passes in 'D'. After printing, the function returns the total number of non-space characters printed. For example, for the example triangle above, the function must return 16. You must call the printSp function, once per line, as part of your solution. (NOTE: Call `printSp` for every line, even when the number of spaces to print is zero.) History:

This is what I have so far I know its not much but its all I understand how to do.

```
if (x >='A' && x <= 'Z')  printf("   A\n   ABA\n  ABCBA\nABCDCBA")
   else  return 0;
```

Comment: post your code so we can see what you've got so far

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

The function printSp() prints spaces.

You currently are outputting a hard coded number of spaces instead of using printSp(). Swap `printf("   ")` for `printSp(3)`

Reading the question, they want you to output a variable number of rows based on the letter provided. So for D you print the pattern you have hard coded which contains four rows and enough letters to output the D. For E you add another row.

I generally suggest students approach problems like this by starting with hardcoding, as you have. Ensure that you incorporate the required features, like printSP(). Then make the code more generic to handle other inputs.